# Generic REST API with Akka HTTP?

Tags: scala, rest, akka, akka-http

Let's say you have 100 models, and for all of them you want the client to be able to do GET/POST/PUT/DELETE.

I read [this article](https://danielasfregola.com/2016/02/07/how-to-build-a-rest-api-with-akka-http/) and a few others, but even with the promising title it seems that a lot of code would have to be duplicated for each model. Boilerplate, as some would call it.

Ideally I want to be able to say something like

```
case class AwesomeCaseClass(primeNumber : Long)
case class EvenMoreAwesomeCaseClass(favoritePrimeNumber : Long)
```

and then specify either all commands that should be accepted for each class (or maybe things like UPSERT).

I cannot find anyone who has done this, can anyone provide a link or a pointer in the right direction?

When Googling I also came across [this](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2016/04/swagger-akka-http/), but for Akka HTTP in particular there seemed to only be support for API *documentation*.

Here is my attempt so far:

```
package route

import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpResponse
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Route
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer

import scala.reflect._
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._
import akka.http.scaladsl.unmarshalling.FromRequestUnmarshaller

/**
  * Created by flyrev on 30.05.16.
  */

case class Test(name: String)

class REST[T](implicit um: FromRequestUnmarshaller[T]) {
  def generateRoute(klazz: Class[_]) : Route = {
    path("test" / klazz.getSimpleName) {
      get {
        complete(HttpResponse(entity = "OK", status = 200))
      } ~ post {
        entity(as[T]) {
              // Insert into DB here
          (zomg) => complete(HttpResponse(entity = "Would have POSTed that stuff", status = 200))
        }
      }
    } ~ get {
      complete(HttpResponse(entity="Not found", status=404))
    }
  }
}

object GenerateRouteFromClass extends App {
  def runtimeClass[T: ClassTag] = classTag[T].runtimeClass
  implicit val system = ActorSystem()
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

  import argonaut._
  import CodecJson.derive

  implicit val um = derive[Test]
  Http().bindAndHandle(new REST[Test].generateRoute(runtimeClass[Test]), "localhost", 8080)
}
```

However, this gives:

```
Error:(45, 24) could not find implicit value for parameter um: akka.http.scaladsl.unmarshalling.FromRequestUnmarshaller[route.Test]
  Http().bindAndHandle(new REST[Test].generateRoute(runtimeClass[Test]), "localhost", 8080)
                       ^
Error:(45, 24) not enough arguments for constructor REST: (implicit um: akka.http.scaladsl.unmarshalling.FromRequestUnmarshaller[route.Test])route.REST[route.Test].
Unspecified value parameter um.
  Http().bindAndHandle(new REST[Test].generateRoute(runtimeClass[Test]), "localhost", 8080)
                       ^
```

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but I think a REST API that requires the user to modify individual model case classes would not be a very good API.

Comment: Not sure what you mean there - ideally I'm only talking about annotations to a case class (or just to a class, if need be).

Comment: Have you check on `macros` ? I think you are able to annotate case classes and use macro to generate all those boiler plate for you, but I never did it

Comment: That's always a possibility. Concrete examples / documentation to do this would be nice. I'm pretty sure that somewhere along the way here I'll be reinventing the wheel.